# "Notice: Undefined variable: db" when using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, function, pdo

On my quest to learn PDO, I wrote this code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY order_cat DESC';
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)
{
    echo "<input type='radio' name='category' value='$row[id]'>$row[name]<br />";
}
```

I then encapsulated it into a function like so:

```
function GetCategory()
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY order_cat DESC';
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='category' value='$row[id]'>$row[name]<br />";
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
echo GetCategory();
```

However, when I do that, I get these errors:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: `db`
>   **Fatal error:** Call to a member function `query()` on a non-object

I don't know what I'm missing; I'm declaring `$db` in my configuration file like so:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$namedb;charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb);
```

Comment: have u declare `$db`?

Comment: yeah in config file $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$localhost;dbname=$namedb;charset=utf8", $userdb, $passdb);

Comment: have you tried any question from the right column? --->

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the $db global as you are inside a function.

```
function GetCategory()
{
global $db;
...
}
```

If it has been defined before of course...

Comment: +1 this solve my problem and show all category but iam still get this error Warning: Missing argument 1 for GetCategory(),

Comment: yeah thanks i learned something new from your answer

Answer (score 3):

You either need to pass `$db` as a parameter to `GetCategory`

```
function GetCategory($db) {
    ...
}
```

or declare it as a global variable:

```
function GetCategory($db) {
    global $db;
    ...
}
```

Parameters are generally preferable.

Comment: +1 this solve my errors and show the categories but 1 error remains Warning: Missing argument 1 for GetCategory(),

Comment: Mark Parnell answered that below his question.

Answer (score 2):

The `$db` object doesn't exist in the context of the function. You should pass it to the function as an additional parameter.

```
function GetCategory($db)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY order_cat DESC';
    foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row)
    {
        echo "<input type='radio' name='category' value='$row[id]'>$row[name]<br />";
    }
}
```

And read up on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: I got this error Warning: Missing argument 1 for GetCategory(), called in line (( function GetCategory($db) ))

Comment: You need to add it to where you call the function too, not just the function definition.

Comment: How much of a beginner are you? All programming languages have function parameters.

Comment: @Barmar i said iam a beginner and still learning

Comment: Beginner in PHP, or beginner in programming computers? You need to learn the basics of programming before you jump all the way to writing database applications.